# swing set bounds causes jpanel to disappear

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I have a JPanel with two Components in them. My layout manager is `null`. When I set the bounds of the two components (I am sure they are in range), they become invisible or disappear. I would like the `toolbar` to be somewhat thin and along the top, and the `field` to fill the rest of the area. Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public final class IDE extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8258005554657842392L;
    private final Toolbar toolbar;
    private final TextEdit field;

    public IDE() {
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.toolbar = new Toolbar();
        this.add(this.toolbar);
        this.field = new TextEdit();
        this.add(this.field);
    }

    private static final class Toolbar extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7947843173691641047L;

        public Toolbar() {
            try {
                this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                Image run = ImageIO.read(new File("buttons/run.png"));
                JButton runButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon(run));
                runButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Building");
                    }
                });
                runButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
                this.add(runButton);
                System.out.println("Toolbar init");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static final class TextEdit extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7089210936444479729L;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        }
    }

    public void validate() {
        super.validate();
        this.toolbar.setBounds(0, 0, this.getWidth(), 50);
        this.field.setBounds(0, 50, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight() - 50);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("[NAME] IDE");
        frame.add(new IDE());
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Please help make these components visible.

Comment: Why use a `null` layout? I don't think I'm the only person that will recommend to avoid it like the plague...

Comment: Use layouts. You won't have this kind of problem. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/

Comment: *would like the toolbar to be somewhat thin and along the top, and the field to fill the rest of the area*: that's a perfect use-case for a BorderLayout with the toolbar at the north and the field in center. Use layout managers, or be prepared for endless pain, and for endless comments telling you to use them.

Comment: Try using `setSize(int width , int height ) `  on the components, also as mentioned above dont use null layout ,it wouldnt scale the components as you resize the frame

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI, you don't use setSize(...). That is the job of the layout manager.

Comment: Why would you override paintComponent() of the TextEdit class and do nothing? Don't do that. Also don't override validate(). That is NOT how you would use a JPanel.

Comment: @camickr he isnt using a layout manager so  `setSize()` should be done by him.

Comment: @JamesSmith could you print the value of the `getWidth()` from inside of the validate and check if it not 0. That could help to solve the problem

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI, setBounds() and setSize() do the same thing when using null layout. The problem is then entire structure of the class, which I pointed out in my comment.

Comment: @Radiodef https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html says that you should use a null layout for absolute location

Comment: *"..says that you should use a null layout for absolute location"*  Yes, but it does not go on to describe the many errors/problems that produces.  The only time you should be setting the location and size of components is if you are **designing a *custom* layout manager.**  So no, don't just toss layouts out the window.  It is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: `frame.setExtendedState(6);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);`  6, 3.. Oh for (other) programmer's sake, don't use 'magic numbers'!  There are constants defined for these things.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I prefer looking at these numbers. I know these numbers well enough. But, I will make these changes for other programmers' sake.

Comment: *"I prefer looking at these numbers"*  That's fine when it's only ever you that sees the code.  For code that might be viewed by *anyone* else (e.g. in an SO question), use the constants!  *"But, I will make these changes for other programmers' sake."*  You sound like you're making a major concession, rather than 'doing the sensible thing'.

Comment: @JamesSmith This tutorial also says that *"If a container holds components whose size is not affected by the container's size [...], then absolute positioning might make sense. [...] However, creating containers with absolutely positioned containers can cause problems if the window containing the container is resized."*

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry if my comment sounded not the best. I've changed it (my question) now; it's just that I find short code better (even though in practice that may not be the best)

Comment: The point we are trying to get across is that null layouts are extraordinarily difficult to get right unless the UI is very simple, and in your case there's no advantage to using it. Using a layout manager will fix all your problems. *"it's just that I find short code better"* Then use a layout manager! It does *everything* for you.